# How to stop cups sticking to placemats

Tags: food

If I ever have a drink and there is a bit of moisture on the bottom of the cup, then it sticks to the placemat, often without me knowing.

Then when I lift the cup up to take a drink, the placemat lifts up as well. Sometimes I notice, and it's just annoying, other times it will fall on the floor or in my food.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Don't use a placemat?

Comment: @bjb568 don't want watermarks everywhere though

Comment: Get new placemats - glass, ceramic or slate, they never, ever stick to a receptacle placed on top, too heavy. Fabric's pretty good, that doesn't usually stick either.

Answer (score 5):

When you pick up your cup, do it by the very bottom, and then use your pinkie to push whatever the cup is sitting on away from the cup. You'll leave the napkin/coaster/placement on the table, and your cup will be in your hand.

Note that this works both right- and left-handed (try it; it's **hard** to pick up a cup with your pinkie on top).

Answer (score 3):

Get into the habit of picking it up by tilting it slightly first.  The seal then breaks at the side that lifts first, and the mat doesn't stick.

Comment: And be sure to press down slightly as you tip.  This will easily pull/pry the rest of the mat off the cup.

Answer (score 1):

Sprinkle a little salt or other small solid particles on the mat before using it. This can prevent the seal from forming between the condensation/residual moisture and allows you to freely use the cup until it's all dissolved.

Comment: Ok, then you get salt plus water, i.e. a brine under the cup or glass. Which means it still sticks, but now you get nasty rings and possibly permanent damage on the placemat or coaster. For non-soluble sprinkles, you get crumbs, which will be or at least appear dirty. Worst case, e.g. for sand, you'd risk scratches. I'm not convinced...

Comment: A friend taught me this at a restaurant one day, because they are always giving you paper napkins which stick like crazy and get all soggy. This works amazingly to fix the problem, so much so that I came here to leave it as an answer. I never hesitate to use it when I'm out, however I would never use it at home, because of the mess of having salt on my table.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let yourself get in the situation from the start.

I'm sure you must have a something... a tea-towel, handkerchief, tissue, kitchen roll, trouser-leg, etc. near to hand.

Dab the bottom of the cup before you leave the kitchen.

Your mat will look nicer for longer too. there's nothing worse than a sticky old place-mat, that the owner doesn't notice... yet everyone else does.

Comment: The trouble with this is that if you have a glass full of something ice cold then condensation will form on the outside and run down onto the mat. You could of course keep a tea-towel or similar on hand to keep wiping it down but its not quite as simple as one wipe at the beginning.

Comment: Besides, isn't this the entire purpose of the mat? Seems kind of pointless to do all that, because you wouldn't need a mat at all in that case.

Comment: Honestly, it's such a dozy question that it doesn't really seem all that important. Use a heavier place mat, stick it down with blu-tack, don't get it wet in the first place. All equally valid...

Answer (score 1):

Add weights to the placemat, or use a heavier placemat. For example, you could glue a small tile to the bottom of a rectangular placemat to weigh it down.

Answer (score 1):

I always make a point of placing the cup so that one very small part of the rim is OFF the placemat, then there's an air gap and no vacuum by which to lift the placemat with the cup.